# Reverse SSH tunnel to an EC2 instance on port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Why does this work:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/ec2-key.pem -N -R 3377:localhost:3377 ec2-user@<ec2-ip4>
```

but this not:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/ec2-key.pem -N -R 80:localhost:80 -R 443:localhost:443 ec2-user@<ec2-ip4>
```

on my EC2 instance?

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 80
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 443
```

Inbound rules of my Security Group:

| Name | Type | Protocol | Port | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SSH | SSH | TCP | 22 | 0.0.0.0/0 |
| SSH RaspberryPi | Custom TCP | TCP | 3377 | 0.0.0.0/0 |
| Website 80 Tunnel | HTTP | TCP | 80 | 0.0.0.0/0 |
| Website 443 Tunnel | HTTPS | TCP | 443 | 0.0.0.0/0 |

Comment: Generally a linux system's configuration allows only  root to  listen on "privileged" ports, ie those below 1024 as mo  The easiest solution is to forward a different port like 8080 or 8443.  You can also look into https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443

Comment: If I want to allow non-root processes to bind to these ports, I can use a tool called setcap from the libcap package. That was the solution, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome to add your own Answer so that future readers can learn from your experience.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this is to allow non-root processes to bind to these "privileged" ports.

```
sudo yum install libcap
```

Then I can set the capabilities on the sshd binary using the setcap command:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/sbin/sshd
```

This should allow non-root users to bind to privileged ports 80 and 443 when using the SSH reverse tunnel.